# How to find the longest monotone subsequence of a sequence?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list, say {5,4,10,16,2,1}.  I want the longest monotone subsequence.  In this case the longest monotone sequence is {5,4,2,1}.

Comment: Weakly or strictly monotone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function will find the longest ascending or the longest descending monotonic sequence in a list of numbers. When the longest ascending sequence is of the same length as the longest descending sequence, it returns both.

```
longestMonotonicSeq[data : {_?NumberQ ..}] :=
  Module[{up, down},
    up = LongestOrderedSequence[data, #1 >= #2 &];
    down = LongestOrderedSequence[data, #2 >= #1 &];
    Switch[Sign[Length[up] - Length[down]],
      1, up,
     -1, down,
      0, {up, down}]]
```

#### Tests

```
longestMonotonicSeq[{5, 4, 10, 16, 2, 1}]
```

> `{5, 4, 2, 1}`

```
longestMonotonicSeq[{10, 11, 3, 25/2, 2, 1, 20, 42.}]
```

> `{10, 11, 25/2, 20, 42.}`

```
longestMonotonicSeq[{10, 3, 16, 2, 1, 17, 20}]
```

> `{{3, 16, 17, 20}, {10, 3, 2, 1}}`